# timezone difference between environments

Tags: java, spring, datetime, redhat

I have an app based on Spring, and it hosted on two environments: **S1** and **S2** - tomcat 8 instances on RedHat servers. The problem is, the time it perceives as *"now"*, for logging and persistence purposes, varies:

- it reports correct time on **S1**
- it is one hour off on **S2**

Environment information:

- Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server 6.9
- JVM Version: 1.8
- -Duser.timezone=Europe/Berlin
- /etc/localtime is the same for both environments

I've written simple debug code, the results differ between environments:

```
System.out.println("[TimeZone]TimeZone ID: " + TimeZone.getDefault().getID());
System.out.println("[TimeZone]TimeZone name: " + TimeZone.getDefault().getDisplayName());

Date date = new Date();
LocalDateTime localDate = LocalDateTime.now();
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");

System.out.println("[Date]Date and time: " + df.format(date));
System.out.println("[LocalDateTime]Date and time: " + formatter.format(localDate));

df.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Europe/Berlin"));
ZonedDateTime zdt = localDate.atZone(ZoneId.of("Europe/Berlin"));

System.out.println("[Date]Date and time in Berlin: " + df.format(date));
System.out.println("[ZonedDateTime]Date and time in Berlin: " + formatter.format(zdt));
```

Results:

**S1**

```
[TimeZone]TimeZone ID: Europe/Berlin
[TimeZone]TimeZone name: Central European Time
[Date]Date and time: 2018-07-10 14:24:52
[LocalDateTime]Date and time: 2018-07-10 14:24:52
[Date]Date and time in Berlin: 2018-07-10 14:24:52
[ZonedDateTime]Date and time in Berlin: 2018-07-10 14:24:52
```

**S2**

```
[TimeZone]TimeZone ID: GMT+01:00
[TimeZone]TimeZone name: GMT+01:00
[Date]Date and time: 2018-07-10 13:29:18
[LocalDateTime]Date and time: 2018-07-10 13:29:18
[Date]Date and time in Berlin: 2018-07-10 14:29:18
[ZonedDateTime]Date and time in Berlin: 2018-07-10 13:29:18
```

some more diagonstic info:

```
xxx@serv1:~ > ls -l /etc/localtime
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 2309 Apr  8  2016 /etc/localtime
xxx@serv1:~ > zdump /etc/sysconfig/clock
/etc/sysconfig/clock  Fri Jul 20 09:21:01 2018

xxx@serv2:~ > ls -l /etc/localtime
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 2309 Feb 13  2014 /etc/localtime
xxx@serv2:~ > zdump /etc/sysconfig/clock
/etc/sysconfig/clock  Fri Jul 20 09:20:47 2018
```

As you might have noticed, TimeZone is not loaded properly for app on **S2**, despite setting the JVM property.

So the question is, how can I correct the time for apps on **S2**? Or at least, how can I investigate this further?

Comment: They don't report the same results. S1 reports CET and S2 GMT+1.. Those are different things... CET can be +1 OR +2 depending on DST... GMT+1 is always well +1 ... I assume they report the same UTC time (within a certain error range). Make sure that there aren't any environment variables on the other box overriding the other settings (or maybe something isn't accessible?!).

Comment: I mean, the output from A and B is the same, it varies between environments. The debug code is ran as a `@PostConstruct` hook. I'm not really versed as a linux admin - which environment variables should I take a look at?

Comment: so if understand correctly app A is printing correct timezone but problem is with app B on S2? am i right? @user

Comment: It's definitely a server time/timezone issue.

Comment: @Deadpool A is printing correct **time**, this occurs in logs from log4j and in database during persist by hibernate, in fields set as `LocalDateTime.now()`. B is one hour off.

Comment: What's the output of `ls -l /etc/localtime`, and what is configured in `/etc/sysconfig/clock` on both systems?

Comment: @FlorianWeimer nothing extraordinary, I think. I just edited the question. However, the problem looks now like it's order of magnitude easier, since both apps started reporting same (wrong) time.

Comment: Wouldnt the first step be to ensure that both S1, and S2 give you the **exact** same information. As said: "Berlin/Europe" and GMT+1 ... do not look "the same". They *should* mean the same, but again: when your servers should be identically configured, your first step should be to *ensure* they are.

Comment: @GhostCat here are tomcat logs from startup: https://pastebin.com/XYxFPVet . I guess we can reduce the question - how despite this configuration can timezone be GMT+1 ?

Comment: This could be a Linux configuration issue. That should be inspected first, as you want any other server (database!) to follow similar times. BTW I would have expected **`cat /etc/localtime`**. Or try the command `timedatectl`.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a simple problem:

on **S1** you have set **Europe/Berlin** as timezone,
while on **S2** you have set **GMT+01:00**

Also you let us know that your actual date was **2018-07-10** which lies in the summer time period of Germany (extracted from S1 timezone Europe/Berlin).

So on **S1** the timezone **Europe/Berlin** varies between GMT+01 and GMT+02 depending on the daylight saving time (summer time) - while on **S2** it is always GMT+01.

This explains your 1 hour difference between S1 and S2.

To fix this you should best change your timezone on **S2** also to **Europe/Berlin** to have the automatic daylight saving time also available there.

The 1 hour off could only be detected during the summer time, but not within the normal (often wrongly called "winter") time.